# WurflDeviceResolver not found

Tags: spring, wurfl, spring-mobile

I found that there was a **WurflDeviceResolver** class in spring-mobile 1.0.0.M3 build. but the same class i didn't find in any release build of spring-mobile.

so is it deprecated? 
what is is the other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a license conflict so the WURFL functionality was removed. Alternatively, Spring Mobile provides numerous extension points, as well as a `LiteDeviceResolver` which detects normal, mobile or tablet devices.